# Linux `mpstat` doesn't work as expected from a crontab script

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I have a script running from root crontab:

```
05 * * * * /bin/bash /root/systat_kpi_tools/systat_kpi.sh
```

The script has an `mpstat` output formatted and saved in CSV format in a file:

```
[[ -e ${BASE_DIR}/cpu_stat_${NOW}.csv ]] || echo "Year,Month,Day,Hr,Min,Sec,%user,%nice,%sys,%iowait,%irq,%soft,%steal,%idle,intr/s" >> ${BASE_DIR}/cpu_stat_${NOW}.csv
mpstat | awk 'NR>3{ print substr($0, index($0,$4)) }' | awk -v dt=$(date +'%Y,%m,%d,%H,%M,%S') -v OFS=, '{$1=dt OFS $1; print}' >> ${BASE_DIR}/cpu_stat_${NOW}.csv
```

Output of the file:

```
# cat cpu_stat_160526.csv
Year,Month,Day,Hr,Min,Sec,%user,%nice,%sys,%iowait,%irq,%soft,%steal,%idle,intr/s
2016,05,26,14,05,01,0.00,2.17,0.08,0.01,0.14,0.00,90.29,1093.83
2016,05,26,15,05,02,0.00,2.19,0.08,0.01,0.14,0.00,90.25,1093.82
```

When I run the command out of the script:

```
# echo "Year,Month,Day,Hr,Min,Sec,%user,%nice,%sys,%iowait,%irq,%soft,%steal,%idle,intr/s" > tmp
# mpstat | awk 'NR>3{ print substr($0, index($0,$4)) }' | awk -v dt=$(date +'%Y,%m,%d,%H,%M,%S') -v OFS=, '{$1=dt OFS $1; print}' >> tmp
# mpstat | awk 'NR>3{ print substr($0, index($0,$4)) }' | awk -v dt=$(date +'%Y,%m,%d,%H,%M,%S') -v OFS=, '{$1=dt OFS $1; print}' >> tmp
# mpstat | awk 'NR>3{ print substr($0, index($0,$4)) }' | awk -v dt=$(date +'%Y,%m,%d,%H,%M,%S') -v OFS=, '{$1=dt OFS $1; print}' >> tmp
```

I get this output:

```
# cat tmp

Year,Month,Day,Hr,Min,Sec,%user,%nice,%sys,%iowait,%irq,%soft,%steal,%idle,intr/s
2016,05,26,15,04,54,7.33,0.00,2.19,0.08,0.01,0.14,0.00,90.25,1093.82
2016,05,26,15,04,57,7.33,0.00,2.19,0.08,0.01,0.14,0.00,90.25,1093.82
2016,05,26,15,04,58,7.33,0.00,2.19,0.08,0.01,0.14,0.00,90.25,1093.82
```

Watch out for the column `%user` having values `7.33,7.33,7.33` which is missing out from previous output when the same line executes from script. Why such weird behavior ?

My Linux flavor is `RHEL5.10 64 bits` :
`kernel-2.6.18-371.el5`

Comment: sourcing the `.bash_profile` in the script did the trick. Now the missing filed shows up. Not sure though why the behavior ? Keeping the question still open for some explanation.

Comment: mpstat indicates that processors statistics are to be reported for the time
       since system startup (boot). that's why u r always getting 7.3. run on terminal with interval like this  mpstat  1 then u will get different values.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a bit old, but I just ran into this today.  As you noted, sourcing the .bash_profile fixed the problem.  In the man page, I found this quote:

> ENVIRONMENT
>         The mpstat command takes into account the following environment variable:
>
> ```
>   S_TIME_FORMAT
>          If  this variable exists and its value is ISO then the current locale will be ignored when printing the date in the report header.
>          The mpstat command will use the ISO 8601 format (YYYY-MM-DD) instead.
> ```

For me the major difference was a 12 vs 24 hour clock, hence needing to awk fields $4,$6 vs $3,$5.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

```
mpstat 1 1
```

Here the explanation why: [mpstat with parameters](https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/217545-mpstat-sar.html)
That will give you only 1 line, and the averages at the bottom. Then, you need to parse that one line (line #4). Also, there is no need to parse the date (or time) given by `mpstat`, you can instead get the current date of the system using `$(date +'FORMAT')`.

Here the script I made, and it works for me. It creates a file if it doesn't exist, and then it adds the results from `mpstat 1 1`. I use `\t` as separator; if you like you can use `,` and change the extension of the file to `*.csv`. You can then add this script to the crontab to run every x minutes.

```
#! /bin/bash
DIR=/somepath
FN=$(date +'CPU-%Y-%m.log')
FN=$DIR/$FN
if [ ! -f $FN ]
then
    touch $FN
    chmod 644 $FN
    printf "Server\tDate\t\t\t%%usr\t%%nice\t%%sys\t%%iowait\t%%irq\t%%soft\t%%steal\t%%guest\t%%gnice\t%%idle\n" > $FN
fi
DATE=$(date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
SERVER="Jupyter"
STAT=$(mpstat 1 1 | awk 'NR==4{printf "%.2f\t%.2f\t%.2f\t%.2f\t%.2f\t%.2f\t%.2f\t%.2f\t%.2f\t%.2f\t", $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13}')
echo -e "$SERVER\t$DATE\t$STAT" >> $FN
```